# How to extract background-url from css definition with scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

How can I extract (with scrapy) `image_1.png` from something like this:

```
<html><body>
<style type="text/css">
img.article_image[class] 
{
    background-image:url('/article_images/image_1.png');
}
</style>    
<img class="article_image">
</body></html>
```

The only idea that comes to my mind is to regexp the source html code, is there anything more elegant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Item Loaders are a great tool, they have the xpath and regex stuff built-in.

```
XPathItemLoader(response).get_xpath(xpath, regex)
```

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html

```
>>> from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
>>> response.body
'<html><body>\n<style type="text/css">\nimg.article_image[class] \n{\n...'
>>> from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
>>> xl = XPathItemLoader(response=response, item={'image': ''})
>>> xl
<scrapy.contrib.loader.XPathItemLoader object at 0x7f5830079f50>
>>> xl.get_xpath('//style', re=r"background-image.*/([^/]+)'")
[u'image_1.png']
>>> xl.add_xpath('image', '//style', re=r"background-image.*/([^/]+)'")
>>> xl.load_item()
{'image': [u'image_1.png']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could locate the css via a xpath query, but you will still have to extract the image path from it using regexps.

So i think using regex on the whole body a good solution here.